# How to add gen.Task module in Tornado webserver running for django backend to allow multiple asynchronous requests

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, tornado

I am trying for the first time to deploy a django website on a microsoft webserver in service mode (without being logged in) using nssm.

To do so, it seems I can't use the usual

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0
```

So I have tried to add a new tornado.py file in my project and the nssm would point to it:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler, RequestHandler, Application, StaticFileHandler

from wsgi import application
from mySite.settings import *


class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hi Tornado")

tr = WSGIContainer(application)
app = Application([
    (r"/tornado", MainHandler), 
    (r"/static/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {'path': STATIC_ROOT}), 
    (r"/media/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {'path': MEDIA_ROOT}),     
    (r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(tr)),     
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(8000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The nssm pointing to this file makes the deployment okay, but unfortunately, I have some long requests calling other APIs in the back-end django and when I call one of these long services, it is impossible to make an other request i.e I have to wait for the first request to be finished.

From what I have seen on other questions related to the same issue on this website, I need to add the tornado decorator below someway:

```
@gen
```

I have tried a couple of options without success and can't find an example working with django.

I use django only for the mvc framework, but have no use of the orm or the auth.

I would have to keep django because there is a lot of work in it and microsoft webserver/nssm because it is the best practice in my company, but is tornado able to help me on this? Am I looking in the right direction?

Thanks in advance to all those who would take time to help me on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Heed the warning on the [`WSGIContainer` docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer): Tornado's `WSGIContainer` has no parallelism and is almost certainly a worse choice than other WSGI servers like `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` for WSGI-based applications.

The `@gen.coroutine` is for native Tornado applications; it is not available in any useful way for foreign applications running inside a `WSGIContainer`.

Tornado's Windows support is also limited.